# How do I install Ubuntu with a usb on a Dell that has no Operating System?

Tags: installation, usb, dell, system

I've been trying to look for this for a while, I only have access to one computer and that is my school computer that has blocks on using a lot of programs thank god I can download Ubuntu. I'm trying to Install Ubuntu onto my Dell Precision 470 workstation through a USB and so far I'm getting no help searching on the internet. So my main question is can I put the .iso onto my usb and plug it into my dell and will it install? Would I have to go into my Boot menu and change the priority to USB and after I do that then what? I'm a bit lost.

EDIT: My school computer is a MacBook Air and since its a school computer most websites are blocked and I'm not able to install any programs. so would I HAVE to use another computer or am I able to use this one?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a bootable USB stick ([instructions for OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)) and then choose USB in the BIOS or boot menu.  Then just follow the installer.

Edit Tue May 21 17:16:17 EDT 2013:

Updated link for OS X instructions per OP's edit.  Doesn't need additional software but does require a bit of command line work.

Answer (score 0):

Use unetbootin to create a live usb, plug it in your pc, go into your bios, set boot priority to usb, install, enjoy ;D